# Xcode always builds all my targets in the current scheme, even without any change

Tags: xcode

With Xcode 8.1 I see this phenomenon that even if I didn't change something on triggering Run Xcode goes through all targets of the selected schema and builds them (which is a mix of mostly C++ and some Obj-C code). All images are processed, all scripts run etc.

However, in the build log I see that the cpp files are not really compiled, they are just listed, so the overall build time is not that of a real build. Still, even with a few seconds on each target I get a delay of 10+ seconds (and a lot of file operations) before the debug session starts actually, which is a pain if you need to restart the debugging session frequently.

Is there any solution to avoid this "pseudo build"?

Comment: Are your source files on a native, local hard disk, or on some sort of network share and/or foreign file system ?

Comment: All files are on an external SSD (via USB 3).

Comment: And the SSD is formatted as HFS+ (i.e. native) or is it FAT (DOS/Windows) ?

Comment: Yes, HFS+ (journaled). The disk is connected via a TB docking station (at one of it's USB 3 ports). But I'm not sure this really matters here. It's rather so that XCode runs clang for every file, every time. Fortunately, clang recognizes that the files haven't changed. Still the entire process takes quite some time (it's a large project).

Comment: OK - I'm all out of ideas then - the only other thing I can suggest that might speed things up would be to move your DerivedData directory onto the local disk (assuming it's currently in the source directory on the external disk), but that's not really addressing the underlying problem. (See `Preferences` -> `Locations`).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm currently experiencing similar issue. Did you find a way to let xcode build only to what the current scheme selected?